# Suppose $g \in C([0,1])$ and $f_{n}$ is a sequence in $C([0,1])$ that converges uniformly to $f$. Prove the equality

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Suppose $g \in C([0,1])$ and $f_{n}$ is a sequence in $C([0,1])$ that converges uniformly to $f$. Prove the equality:  $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x)g(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx$$.

I had two different views on how to approach this:

**Approach 1: (Feels as if it might be too good to be true)**

Since this is a sequence of continuous functions on a compact set, by the Integral Convergence Theorem:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x)g(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}(x)g(x) dx  = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx$$

**Approach 2**

Proving $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x)g(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx \\ \iff \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x) dx = 0$$

That being the case we examine:

$$|f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \leq |g(x)(f_{n}(x) - f(x)| + |f(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)|$$

Since $[0,1]$ is compact we know by the Extreme Value THeorem, there exists $ x_{0} \in [0,1]$ such that $g(x) \leq g(x_{0}) =\ max$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

As well we are given $f_{n}$ converge uniformly to $f$. So for all $\epsilon > 0 $ the is a $N > 0$ s.t $\|f_{n}(x) - f(x)\|_{\infty} < \frac{\epsilon}{|g(x_{0})|}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Therefore:

$$|g(x)(f_{n}(x) - f(x)| + |f(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \leq |g(x)||(f_{n}(x) - f(x)| + |f(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \leq |g(x)|\ \|(f_{n}(x) - f(x)\|_{\infty} + |f(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \leq |g(x_{0})| \frac{\epsilon}{|g(x_{0})|} = \epsilon$$

Thoughts on the solutions? Any of them correct?

Comment: What does "Integral convergence theorem" state?

Comment: Your method $1$ is correct because it is uniformly convergent on a finite interval!

Comment: The integral convergence theorem is not valid unless $f_n\to f$ uniformly, and is just what you need to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 is correct a can  far as you can justify that $f_ng\to fg$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ (and is a good and easy method). Method 2 is uselessly complicated. An other good method is:

**3rd method**
$$\left|\int_0^1(f_ng-fg)\right|\leq \underbrace{\sup_{[0,1]}|f_n-f|}_{\to 0\text{ if }n\to \infty }\int_0^1 |g|\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$$

Comment: I was thinking of pulling that out of the expression. ....Out of curiosity, even though it is uselessly complicated is it a valid proof?

Comment: I don't have time to check in detail... first why do you use $|g(x)(f_n(x)-f(x))|\leq |g(x)(f_n(x)-f(x))|+\underbrace{|f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x)|}_{=0}$ this is highly non-relevant. At the end you didn't conclude anything... but you try to reproduce the proof of $f_n\to f$ uniformly implies you can permute limits and integral...